# why can't I sync flutter project with gradle files in android studio

Tags: gradle

I am using android studio dolphin. I need to sync the project with the gradle files. There is supposed to be a button to do this in the "files" menu and in the toolbar. These buttons do not show up for me.
However, when I open the build.gradle file and click "open for editing in android studio" it opens the file in a separate window and then the buttons show up. I click to sync it and it says that it completes successfully. When I go back to the original window with the project, I am still unable to see any build variants which indicates that there is still an issue with the gradle files or something.

I tried syncing the files when I opened the new window with only the build.gradle file. I was expecting build variants to show up. They did not